# Asp.net MVC4 Bootstrap tab dynamically composed : how to set the first item with active class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a view linked to a ViewModel and I set up a multi tab nav dynamically. Everything is fine But I can't succeed to write a if condition when Category Id is one to start with the first tab in Active State.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    @foreach (var item in Model.LesCategories)
{ 
        <li><a href="#tabs-@item.Id" data-toggle="tab">@item.Nom</a> </li>
}
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    @foreach (var item in Model.LesCategories)
    {

        <div id="tabs-@item.Id" class=" tab-pane">
            <table>
                @foreach (var plat in Model.LesPlats)
                {
                    if (plat.Category.Id == item.Id)
                    { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(platItem => plat.Nom)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret">
                                </span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Edit/@item.Nom">Modifier</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Details/@item.Nom">Détails</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Delete/@item.Nom">Supprimer</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            }

        }
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
        </p>
}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify my code, probably my razor code could be improved but it works

```
@{
    var tabActive = "";
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    @foreach (var item in Model.LesCategories)
    {

        if (item.Id == 1)
        {
            tabActive = "active"; 
        }
        else
        {
            tabActive = ""; 
        }


      <div id="tabs-@item.Id" class=" tab-pane @tabActive">
            <table>
                @foreach (var plat in Model.LesPlats)
                {
                    if (plat.Category.Id == item.Id)
                    { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(platItem => plat.Nom)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret">
                                </span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Edit/@item.Nom">Modifier</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Details/@item.Nom">Détails</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Plat/Delete/@item.Nom">Supprimer</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }

                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
        </p>
        }

</div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to my own question:
It was just a Razor understanding basic problem:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">

    @foreach (var item in Model.LesCategories)
{ 
        <li class="@(item.Id == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a  href="#tabs-@item.Id" data-toggle="tab" >@item.Nom</a> </li>
}
</ul>
```

It's doing correctly the selection of the tab but don't display the tab content..... :)